# How does Anivia's passive interact with unique item passives, item activations, and summoner spells?

Tags: league-of-legends

Does Anivia still retain unique item effects while in egg form, such as Thornmail? Can she activate items like Deathfire Grasp? What summoner spells can she use, if she can use any at all?

Comment: Does the egg technically have 0 movement speed? What would happen if you used malphite Q on her? Just damage? Her egg really is pretty unique, raises a lot of good questions. It would be amazingly hilarious to see someone die to an egg with thornmail.

Answer (score 5):

[Anivia's Ability Details](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Anivia_the_Cryophoenix/Ability_Details)

---

**Rebirth**

> While in this [egg] form Anivia cannot move or use any abilities

- No item active abilities
- No summoner spells

---

It's undocumented whether item passive abilties still apply, so it's a great candidate for testing.

Answer (score 3):

She's effectively stunned, so no active abilities or summoners. She does keep the same armor/magic resist, although the passive adds a modifier on top of that (negative at low levels, scaling up to +20 at level 15). I'm pretty sure Thornmail and similar passives still apply. Note that Guardian Angel is a special case: it triggers before the egg, so if you're in egg form it means you already used up Guardian Angel and it's on cooldown.

Comment: Can you include a source that shows that item passives still apply? Or could you record some simple tests?

Comment: +1, and ty for specifically mentioning GA - was about to ask question on exactly this situation ;)

Answer (score 2):

While in egg form Anivia can't use any spells, item actives, or summoner spells.

She is basically a suppressed champion with different stats, although...

Items with passives like Thornmail, Frozen Heart, Abyssal Scepter... are still applied because the egg is still considered a champion. This differs from another champion with a revival passive, Zac, as his blobs are not considered to be a champion.

Revive effects are always triggered before the passive effect, the same applies to champions such as Aatrox, Karthus, Kogmaw and Sion.

Answer (score -2):

Nothing of all that. She can't use items. Also her resistances drop to 0 and the passive effects of her items are lost.

Comment: Please be careful in your answers, her resistances do not drop to 0, but instead are modified by -40 / -25 / -10 / +5 / +20 depending on level - [Anivia Rebirth](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Anivia_the_Cryophoenix/Ability_Details)